# Unity Photon как посмотреть пользователей НЕ в комнате

Tags: c#, unity3d

пользователей в комнате могу посмотреть так:
foreach (Player player in PhotonNetwork.PlayerList){чтото с ними сделать}

подскажите пожалуйста, как посмотреть тех кто только зашел в приложение, но не в комнату, не в лобби

у кого статус подключения: ConnectedToMasterServer
того кто подсчитывается по команде: PhotonNetwork.CountOfPlayersOnMaster

то есть количество этих игроков считается, но как их вывести, чтобы получить к ним доступ в справке не вижу

вижу только указанный выше PlayerList
и PlayerListOthers, который содержит других игроков, но которые также находятся в комнате